# Laravel 8 vendor class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory` can't resolve name of ModelNameFactory class

Tags: laravel

Laravel 8 has the default `App/Models` directory for Model classes. The `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory` has static function `resolveFactoryName()` to resolve name of ModelNameFactory class

```
    public static function resolveFactoryName(string $modelName)
    {
        $resolver = static::$factoryNameResolver ?: function (string $modelName) {
            $modelName = Str::startsWith($modelName, 'App\\Models\\')
                ? Str::after($modelName, 'App\\Models\\')
                : Str::after($modelName, 'App\\');

            return static::$namespace.$modelName.'Factory';
        };

        return $resolver($modelName);
    }
```

The function works properly only for `App/ModelName` or `App/Models/ModelName`
if name of Model class, for example, is the `Domain/Customers/Models/ModelName`, that function doesn't work properly. What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: Where did you create your factory? in `database\factories\ModelNameFactory.php`?

Comment: Yes, my factory is in `database\factories\ModelNameFactory.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.html#method_guessFactoryNamesUsing), there is a method called `guessFactoryNamesUsing` which lets you tell Laravel how it should guess the name of your factories.

Add the following to your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

public function register()
{
    Factory::guessFactoryNamesUsing(function ($class) {
        return 'Database\\Factories\\' . class_basename($class) . 'Factory';
    });
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php#L665):

```
/**
 * Specify the callback that should be invoked 
 * to guess factory names based on dynamic relationship names.
 *
 * @param  callable  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public static function guessFactoryNamesUsing(callable $callback)
{
    static::$factoryNameResolver = $callback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put this in your model class in `App\Models\ModelName`.
Make sure the `ModelFactory` is the factory name.

```
protected static function newFactory()
{
    return \Modules\Module\Database\Factories\ModelFactory::new();
}
```